# updating subdocument in a modern way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hi there i came up with this solution after looking at an old post here in stackoverflow . The solituion is working fine , my only question is "there isn't a better way of doing this?".

With the last version of mongoose there isn't a way of updating a subdocument in an array simply using findOneAndUpdate ?

here is the code

```
exports.updateDeliveryCheck = async (req, res) => {
  const values = new ParamsFormatter(req).query;
  const pageId = await TemperaturesPage.findOne({ date: values.date });
  TemperaturesPage.findById(pageId._id, (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      if (!result) {
        res.status(404).send('Diary page not found');
      } else {
        result.delivery.id(values.Id).temp = +values.temp;
        result.save((saveerr, saveresult) => {
          if (!saveerr) {
            res.status(200).send(saveresult);
          } else {
            res.status(400).send(saveerr.message);
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).send(err.message);
    }
  });
};
```

here are the schemas

```
const DeliveryCheckSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  product: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name product missing'],
  },
  supplier: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Supplier name missing'],
  },
  temp: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Delivery temperature missing'],
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
  },
  actionTaken: {
    type: String,
  },
  signature: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Signature is missing , you are probably not logged in '],
  },
  note: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const TemperaturesPageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Date for new diary page missing'],
  },
  delivery: [DeliveryCheckSchema],
});
```

as requested I add a sample data

```
{
    "date": {
        "$date": "2021-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "delivery": [{
        "product": "mozzarella",
        "supplier": "prestige",
        "temp": 8,
        "date": {
            "$date": "2021-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "signature": "cristian",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61bb45a94873a3a5d7ae365e"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can we also have the sample dataset, request body used for updating and also the corresponding output?

Comment: hi ray , i'm sending all the request with the params . i'm not sure what do you mean by output .. it returns the new document updated .. i'm new to mongodb .. i'm doing this to learn

Comment: A question _to ask yourself_ is that why are you querying the `TemperaturesPage` twice, in successive statements?

Comment: the reason I've done that is that i wasn't sure I could do this method with `findOne` instead than `findById`. And as didn't want to send client side the id of the page i couldn't find another solution... My code can be improved for sure , anyway my question was about the possibility to do it differently with mongoose .. I was thinking that maybe there is a built in method,instead of using an arrow function .. hope make sense